# Passing variables from Python GUI to PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

So I am creating an application that can connect printers with a Python GUI that runs PowerShell scripts in the background. I was wondering if there was a way I could pass a variable inputted from a Python widget into a PowerShell script that is being invoked by Python. This variable would be the name of the printer that I could specify in Python so that I do not have to create separate scripts for each printer.

My code in Python that calls upon the PS script:

```
def connect():               
        if self.printerOpts.get() == 'Chosen Printer':
            subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",'-ExecutionPolicy','Unrestricted', '.\'./ScriptName\';'])
```

PS script that connects printer to computer:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\server\printer -AsJob
```

Basically, I am wondering if I can pass a variable from Python into the "printer" part of my PS script so that I do not have to create a different script for each printer that I would like to add.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this would be completely in PowerShell or complete in Python.

What you're after is doable. You can pass it in the same way that you have passed `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, by ensuring that the PowerShell script is expecting the variable.

My Python is non-existant so please bear with if that part doesn't work.

**Python**

```
myPrinter # string variable in Python with printer name
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",'-ExecutionPolicy','Unrestricted', '.\'./ScriptName\';','-printer',myPrinter])
```

**PowerShell**

```
param(
    $printer
)

Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\server\$printer -AsJob
```

Comment: Thanks gmss0ulman. I was able to apply the changes, but PowerShell is giving an error "The specified server does not exist" and the printer is no longer adding.

Comment: @JDawg Hmm.. what does the string that you are passing to PowerShell look like? Maybe it should be just `$printer` instead of `\\server\$printer`

Comment: @gmss0ulman I used your PS script and made some other changes to the Python script and it worked. I posted my answer on the question if you were curious. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked for me was first to specify that I was passing a variable as a string in my PS script:

```
param([string]$path)

Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\server\$path
```

My PS script was not expecting this variable. In my Python script I had to first define the my variable which named path as a string and then input "path" into the end of my subprocess function.

```
        path = "c"
        subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",'-ExecutionPolicy','Unrestricted', 'Script.ps1', path])
```